# How does complete convergence imply almost sure covergence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$,... be a sequence of random variables on a probability space ($\Omega$ , F , $\mu$). The definition of complete convergence is for $\epsilon$>0, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{\lvert Y_n-Y \lvert > \epsilon \} < \infty.$$

What I believe to be the definition of almost sure convergence is,

$$ P(w: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}Y_n = Y) = P( \bigcup_{\epsilon>0 \ rationals}  \bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n > m}^{\infty} \ \{ |Y_n - Y| < \epsilon \}) = 1  $$

Like the answer below suggested. We the apply the Borel-Cantelli Lemma which states

$$ \ If \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n)< \infty, \ then \ P(A_n \ i.o) = P(  \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}\ A_n) = P(\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n = m}^{\infty}A_n)=0.$$
From our assumptions, since we know for any $\epsilon>0$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{\lvert Y_n-Y \lvert > \epsilon \} < \infty$. 
If we define $A_n= {|Y_n -Y|>\epsilon}$, we can say $$P(\bigcup_{\epsilon>0  \ rationals \ } \bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n = m}^{\infty} \{|Y_n-Y|> \epsilon \})=0.$$

Thus applying De-Morgans Law we can say, $$ P(\bigcap_{\epsilon>0 \ rationals \ } \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} \{ |Y_n-Y| < \epsilon\}) = 1. $$

This implies $$ P( \bigcup_{\epsilon > 0 \ rationals}\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} \{ |Y_n-Y| < \epsilon\}) = 1. $$

We can also note $$\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} \{ |Y_n-Y| < \epsilon\} \le  \bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n = m}^{\infty} \{|Y_n-Y|< \epsilon \}.$$

Is this enough to show it converges almost surely? I remember being told you also have to show the two sets on both the LHS and RHS have the same elements? If so how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I think your statement $P( \bigcup_{\epsilon>0 \ rationals}  \bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n > m}^{\infty} \ \{ |Y_n - Y| < \epsilon \}) = 1$ for almost sure convergence is mistaken, and should be $P( \bigcap_{\epsilon>0 \ rationals}  \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n > m}^{\infty} \ \{ |Y_n - Y| < \epsilon \}) = 1$, which takes care of your problem (your applications of Borel-Cantelli and De Morgan are enough to do the job).